# background image is not showing in smaller screens while moving horizontally

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, resolution, screen-resolution

I designed a website with 960 grid system and applied a background image and alternate color through CSS for header and footer as below,

```
html {
height: 100%;
background: url(../images/htmlbg1.jpg) repeat-x;
} 

body {
font-family:Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12px;
margin:0;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background:url(../images/headerdrbg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
}

footer { 
width:100%; padding:12px 0px; 
background:#404040 url(../images/footertop1.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
color:#808080; 
}
```

It's working fine across most browsers.  It's looking fine small screen too. But when I scrolled horizontally, I'm unable to see the background image (ie.headerdrbg.jpg and footertop1.jpg). See attached image. [screenshot of footer after moved the scroll bar horizontally in 640x480px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw4OH.png)

Please help me to find solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the 960 GS you shouldn't be having this problem, because they have a min-width on the `body`. Ensure you haven't deleted this, or alter the value if your layout is wider than 960px:

```
/*
  Forces backgrounds to span full width,
  even if there is horizontal scrolling.
  Increase this if your layout is wider.

  Note: IE6 works fine without this fix.
*/

body {
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. you were right. In my 960_16_col.css it was commented.

Comment: You could thank by formally [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. That is quite an established (and nice, too) form of thanking here on SO. :)